# Java 2 ArrayLists with same elements in same order returns false on equals check

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I have a test case to check my sorting method for a list of objects, I have printed the contents of the two lists after sorting and they have the same elements in the same order. However testList.equals(correctList) returns false. Does anyone know why?

The test case

```
List<KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames> correctList = new ArrayList<KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames>();
        List<KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames> testList = new ArrayList<KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames>();
        correctList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 5, 1000, "A"));
        correctList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 4, 1000, "A"));
        correctList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 3, 1234, "A"));
        correctList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 2, 1000, "A"));
        correctList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 1, 1000, "A"));
        testList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 1, 1000, "A"));
        testList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 3, 1234, "A"));
        testList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 5, 1000, "A"));
        testList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 2, 1000, "A"));
        testList.add(new KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames("A", 4, 1000, "A"));
        KthPopularNamesReport testReport = new KthPopularNamesReport(testList, "", "", 0, 0);
        testReport.sortKthPopularNamesList();
        System.out.println(testReport.getKthPopularNamesList().equals(correctList));
        for (int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++)
        {
            KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames currentName2 = testList.get(i);
            KthPopularNamesReport.KthPopularNames currentName = testReport.getKthPopularNamesList().get(i);
            System.out.println(currentName.getName()+" "+currentName.getFrequency()+" "+currentName.getOccurrence()+" "+currentName.getPercentage()+" ");
            System.out.println(currentName2.getName()+" "+currentName2.getFrequency()+" "+currentName2.getOccurrence()+" "+currentName2.getPercentage()+" ");
        }
```

The output

```
false

A 5 1000 A 

A 5 1000 A 

A 4 1000 A 

A 4 1000 A 

A 3 1234 A 

A 3 1234 A 

A 2 1000 A 

A 2 1000 A 

A 1 1000 A 

A 1 1000 A
```

Comment: Check the list equals method implementation code. Does it compare the elements or the list object reference for equality? In case it checks equality for reference then your equals check will never succeed.

Comment: `List`'s `equals()` compares each element using the element's `equals()` method. Check you have implemented `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in `KthPopularNames`.